# Variable is Undefined within useState setter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, use-state

I've implemented the following function to handle the text input:

```
const handleChange = input => e => {
    const val = e.target.value.trim();
    val &&
        setValues(v => ({
            ...v,
            [input]: val,
        }));
};
```

I've defined `values` as follows:

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        description: '',
        someExtraFields: ''
});
```

The function would be called as follows:

```
<input
  onChange={handleChange('name')}
/>
```

The code above works fine, however the version below does not. It throws the error `cannot read value of undefined`.

I'm not sure why this happens, as when I attempt to log `e.target.value()` above the `setValues` call, it works fine - is there something I'm missing here to do with using it within the `setValues` method?

```
const handleChange = input => e => {
    e.target.value &&
        setValues(v => ({
            ...v,
            [input]: e.target.value.trim();,
        }));
};
```

Comment: `e.target.value` is a synthesized event object by react which gets grabage collected very early by react. If you were setting values directly without the callback it would still hold the reference to the event object but by the time your callback gets called the event object being referenced would have been garbage collected. You must copy the value from the reference so it can be accessed in a closure scope by the callback, as you did in the first example

Comment: Did you intend to end your value with a semicolon in the second example? `[input]: e.target.value.trim();,`